# Resize and rotate an ImageView in Android

Tags: android, image, matrix, rotation

I generate an ImageView dynamically. And I want to change its size to make a square, and then rotate it. Thats the result:

At the begining:

[image: At the beging]

On long click over the imageView. I set the hight equals to the widht, and chang the background to notice it:

[image]

A Seek Bar Apears to set the degrees of the rotation and when I change it happens this:

[image]
[image]

When I start te rotation the position of the original image change and I dont know why.

The code:

```java
//selectedImage its the imageView in wich you do a long click
img.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            selectImg = (ImageView) v;
            selectImg.getLayoutParams().height = selectImg.getWidth();

            selectImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);


            seekBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });


seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            int w = selectImg.getWidth();
            int h = selectImg.getHeight();

            selectImg.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

            matrix.postRotate(seekBar.getProgress(),w/2 , h/2);
            selectImg.setImageMatrix(matrix);  
            field.invalidate();
        }
```

The problem is that becaouse of this change of position, de rotation center is not in the midle of the original image. The idea is to have exactly the same image but rotated.The question is, why does this change of position happend? And how can I solve it?
 I need to know that beacouse now I'm trying to set the size of the image depending on the rotation. So without know that I can't repositioning the original image.

Comment: And what's the question ?

Comment: selectImg is an ImageView?

Comment: Matrix matrix = selecting.getImageMatrix()

Comment: Yes selectImg is an ImageView. It is created dynamically

Comment: ok, then try to translate it in (w/2, h/2), rotate, and traslate it againg in (-w/2, -h/2)

Comment: It worked. If you had told me that in a question I would had gave you a  credit.

Comment: I still need to know why the position chages because now I'm trying to set the size of the image depending on the rotation. So without know that I can't repositioning the original image.